# How to temporarily switch to the GUI thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a program that takes a long action, I run this function on a different thread. Periodically I need to update the information for the user, so I send a signal to the GUI thread. But sometimes I need the user to make a choice, I need to display the QDialog on the GUI thread and pause the slow thread while the user selects an option, and when the user completes the selection, return the value to the slow thread and continue it

it should look something like this:

But I don’t know how to stop and continue the thread and whether it should be done this way.

Header:

```
class Example:public QObject
{
    //...
    Q_OBJECT
    void mainLoop();
    Example();
signals:
    void updateGUI(const QString &message);
    void sendQuestion(const QString &message);
    void continueMainLoop(const QString &answer);
private slots:
    void updatuGUIslot(const QString &message);
    void showQuestionDialog(const QString &message);
};
```

Source:

```
  Example::Example()
  {
    connect(this,&Example::updateGUI,this,&Example::updatuGUIslot);
    connect(this,&Example::sendQuestion,this,&Example::showQuestionDialog);
    
    std::thread t(&Example::mainLoop,this);
    t.detach(); 
    // in the project it is not in the constructor
  }

void Example::mainLoop() 
{
    while(some condition1)
    {
        // slow action
        if(some condition2)
            emit updateGUI("message");
        if(some condition3)
        {
            QString result;
            ThreadPtr th = this_thread(); // pseudocode
            connect(this,&Example::continueMainLoop,this,[&](const QString &answer) 
            {
                result = answer;
                th.continue(); // pseudocode
            });
            emit sendQuestion("question");
            th.wait(); // pseudocode
        }
        // slow action
    }
}
void Example::showQuestionDialog(const QString &message)
{
    // show dialog with question
    emit continueMainLoop("answer");
}
void Example::updatuGUIslot(const QString &message)
{        
    // update GUI
}
```

Comment: Sounds like [`Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) might be useful in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to invoke the method with BlockingQueuedConnection before condition3 for checking which option that selected by the user.

```
bool updateGui ;
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "showDialog",Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection,
                          Q_RETURN_ARG(bool, updateGui));
if(updateGui)
{
    //update GUI
}
```

Comment: when we are using BlockingQueuedConnection caller thread, we will be waiting for the return value.

Comment: if I add this lines in main loop `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "test",Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection,
                                      Q_RETURN_ARG(bool, updateGui));`  `void Example::test()
{ cmd << "test \n"; }` then nothing happens and updateGui is false

Comment: updateGUI variable is the return value of the test function and you must return a boolean value in the test function if you want to change the updateGUI variable. Please read the official document ------- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod

Comment: Oh thanks, I thought that the success of the method call is written in this variable, now it works